Is there a way to program an ePaper HAT with Python on a RPi Zero?
I'm having a problem with an ePaper that I'm trying to program in Python.
Actually, it's powered on a RPi Zero.
I've made this program and there's this output :
e-Paper busy
e-Paper busy release
Clear...
e-Paper busy
e-Paper busy release
Horizontal
Horizontal
e-Paper busy
e-Paper busy release
spi end
close 5V, Module enters 0 power consumption ...

The program :
import sys
sys.path.append(r'lib')

import epd2in7b as epdlib
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import math
import traceback

try:
    epd = epdlib.EPD()
    epd.init()
    print("Clear...")
    epd.Clear()

    w,h=epdlib.EPD_WIDTH, epdlib.EPD_HEIGHT

    HBlackimage = Image.new('1', (h, w), 255)
    HRedimage = Image.new('1', (h, w), 255)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(HBlackimage)

    draw.text((0,0), 'Hello World', font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf', 30), fill = 0)

    epd.display(epd.getbuffer(HBlackimage), epd.getbuffer(HRedimage))
    epd.sleep()

except :
    print ('traceback.format_exc():\n%s',traceback.format_exc())
    exit()

After that, nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas?

Since you have not shown us “this program”, we cannot say anything about possible errors.

Sorry, I forgot
